# iOS do scheduled operation in background or when app active

Tags: ios, swift

I have CoreData model which I want to update at 12 AM. So it's kind of an even when the app can recognize that a new day is coming and at 12 AM change some things in data models.

Initially, the idea was:
Prepare a single function that returns updated data. So before the function returns smth I every time check for the time (NSDate interval between two dates) and then update data model (if it's a new day). But the architecture not so simple for this purpose and it will take some time to prepare for a single point where I can get updated data, also it takes some time in background to update CoreData model which also adds some expenses to this task.

Is this ok solution to use some timer which will update data at 12 AM, I don't care about consistency in this case, but I don't like a timer which is checking every single second is 12 AM already or not. Is there some push notification update or some scheduler manager in iOS which can update data for me. One more time I just want to update the data layer and I don't care about consistency in UI. If consistency matter for sure then I would like to follow initial ide with a single point of retrieving data.

So I probably need some scheduler manager for this purpose or rewrite code of how I get the data.

Comment: You can't execute code at a specific time when your app is suspended. Typically you would just check the time the nets time your app comes to the foreground and determine if it should of the work based on the date.  You could also use background fetch or the new iOS 13 background tasks but you would still need to check the time as there is no guarantee as to when iOS will launch your background operation.

Comment: As other have stated you cannot schedule a task like this. You could send a notification or you can look at [applicationSignificantTimeChange(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622992-applicationsignificanttimechange?language=swift).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to execute a function at regular intervals, even when the app is backgrounded/killed by the user.

The most reliable solution for executing a function at regular intervals even when the app is backgrounded is to use push notifications scheduled for the specific time intervals (midnight each day in your case), which would wake up the app and let it update its data. However, this solution has its downsides, since you need a server to send the push notification from and the users device needs to be connected to the internet. Also, push notifications don't wake up the app in case the user manually killed it.

For your particular problem, the best solution would be to refactor your code in a way that you have a single function that can be used to retrieve data and hence this function could ensure the data is updated in case a certain time interval has passed since the last update.

Comment: yea agree with you, just wanted to know maybe there is some solution, where interesting suggestion with iOS 13, but we have not prepared for it yet) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into [BGProcessingTask.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgprocessingtask) You won't have granular control over when you're granted CPU time but you can set the interval you'd prefer that the task execute. Ultimately, when you run and how often is up to the system.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the new BackgroundTasks Framework Apple releases for iOS 13. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks

While you are not guaranteed at specific time if you have a window (12 am - 3 am) scheduling background tasks may be sufficient for you.